# http header - origin

Tags: http, header

I have a question about "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".
For example, I have 2 web sites, http://myweb1.com and http://myweb2.com.

http://myweb1.com provides xmlRequest and http://myweb2.com ask http://myweb1.com to get the response.

With "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" I can authorize http://myweb1.com to give a response to http://myweb2.com.

But Is it possible to block http://myweb1.com to give response to himself ?
To resume is it possible to refuse/block non-cross origin ressource ?

Comment: Domain 2 is for sale, are you sure its yours?

Comment: It is an example :)

Comment: Not very clear what you want to do, if you want to stop an Ajax request issued from myweb1 being serviced by myweb1 you should implement some kind of authentication method in your post, you cannot use CORS because as they are the same domain there will be no pre-flight at all.

Comment: Thank a lot ! So if I understand, I have to check if the HTTP_REFERER is myweb1 or not ? If it is myweb1, I have to return "null".

Comment: I cant remember if Ajax set the referrer, remember that even if it does its not 100% reliable and should never be trusted.